# Using global variables in Celery: What's the best approach?

Tags: python, django, celery

Im writing an app using Django 1.10 and Celery.
Im trying to create a loop in celery that can be started and stopped through Django.

My idea looks something like this (very simple):

```
_run = False

def do_work():
  global _run
  while _run:
    # Do something

@app.task
def start():
  global _run
  _run = True
  do_work()

@app.task
def stop():
  global _run
  _run = False
```

The problem is that celery is typically run in >1 working thread, and _run is not accessable between threads.

**Question:** What's the best approach to achieve the functionality?
Im thinking about setting a database variable, but I'm afraid its not the best approach.

Comment: This seems like an XY question. Why do you want a loop at all?

Comment: The loop will be polling data from external APIs and populate the systems database. I dont understand what you mean with 'XY question'.

Comment: why are you using Celery tasks? seems like wrong use case

Answer (score 1):

One of possible approaches is to create task which will run forever and then stop it on request.

```
from proj.celery import app
app.control.revoke(task_id)
```

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/faq.html#can-i-cancel-the-execution-of-a-task